# Bad arguments passed to org.jboss.resteasy.spi.metadata.ResourceMethod

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, resteasy

I am exposing an EJB as RESTful Service in wildfly 8.2 standalone mode.
The EJB is deployed in an ear archive.

The call of the service results to:

```
Bad arguments passed to org.jboss.resteasy.spi.metadata.ResourceMethod
```

This happens, when resteasy wants to invoke my method with reflection.

I registered a @Provider which deserialises the JSON into a Java Object - works proper.
The Proxy for my EJB seems to be invalid.
The expression:

```
arg0 instanceof server.ejb.GenericFactoryRest
```

evaluates to

```
error(s)_during_the_evaluation
```

in the debugger.
The toString() of arg0 shows:

```
Proxy for view class: server.ejb.GenericFactoryRest of EJB: GenericFactoryRest
```

When i deploy my ejb as an war archive, all works proper, but i need all as ear.

best regards

Answer (score 0):

See [JAX-RS 2.0 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/index.html), 2.3.2 Servlet:

> A JAX-RS application is packaged as a Web application in a .war file.
>   The application classes are packaged in WEB-INF/classes or WEB-INF/lib
>   and required libraries are packaged in WEB-INF/lib.

You can't have JAX-RS web resources in an EJB.